# Re-starting a timer after stopping it

Tags: javascript, html, timer, setinterval

**Problem:** When I click my start button after stopping my timer, I can't seem to get the timer to resume.

**Desired result:** For any given timer, when I click the start button, after clicking the stop button, I want the time to resume where it left off.

I figured that when clicking the start button, it would just call the setInterval function again after being cleared, however, I am having issues figuring that out.

I have the stop event in each function in the same scope as the intervalID var's, which hold the setInterval functions itself. Which is why the stop button works. Calling the timer functions(setPomodoro, setLongBreak, setShortBreak) resets their timer's to the original state. I can't seem to grasp how to resume from the timer's time when it's stopped.

**JSBIN:** http://jsbin.com/bucalequsi/edit?html,js,output

**Re-creation:**

```
//  Problem: Pomodor timer does not have functionality
//  Solution: Add functionality to the pomodor timer.
//      IF a break timer is running WHILE another is clicked, stop running timer, start clicked timer.
//      Reset current interval time on reset button.
//      If break buttons are clicked more than once, reset the time.
window.onload = function() {

    var pomodoro = document.querySelector('#set-time'),
        longBreak = document.querySelector('#long-brk'),
        shortBreak = document.querySelector('#short-brk'),
        stopButton = document.querySelector('#stop'),
        startButton = document.querySelector('#start'),
        resetButton = document.querySelector('#reset'),
        container = document.querySelector('#container'),
        actionButtons = document.querySelector('#buttons'),
        timer = document.querySelector('#timer');

   //  Click event for break timers.    
    container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
//      store event target
        var el = e.target;
            if (el === pomodoro) {
                setPomodoro();
            } else if (el === longBreak) {
                setLongBreak();
            } else if (el === shortBreak) {
                setShortBreak();
            }
            e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);  


//  1.1a Create a timer that counts down from 25 minutes.
    function setPomodoro() {
        var mins = 24;
        var secs = 60;
        var intervalID = setInterval(function() { //set unique interval ID for each SI func.
                timer.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs;
                secs--;
                if (secs === 0) {
                    mins--;
                    secs = 60;
                } 
            }, 1000);
//      2.2 When stop button is clicked, timer stops
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
               clearInterval(intervalID);
        }, false);

    }

//  1.2a Create a timer that counts down from 10 minutes
    function setLongBreak() {
        var mins2 = 9;
        var secs2 = 60;
        var intervalID2 = setInterval(function() {
                timer.innerHTML = mins2 + ':' + secs2;
                secs2--;
                if (secs2 === 0) {
                    mins2--;
                    secs2 = 60;
                }
            }, 1000);
         stopButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            clearInterval(intervalID2);
        }, false);
    }
//  1.3a Create a timer that counts down from 5 minutes.
    function setShortBreak() {
        var mins3 = 4;
        var secs3 = 60;
        var intervalID3 = setInterval(function() {
                timer.innerHTML = mins3 + ':' + secs3;
                secs3--;
                if (secs3 === 0) {
                    mins3--;
                    secs3 = 60;
                }
            }, 1000);
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            clearInterval(intervalID3);
        }, false);
    }
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pomodoro Timer</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <div id="header"><h1>Pomodoro Timer</h1></div>
        </header>
        <div class="row">
            <ul id="breaks">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Pomodoro" id="set-time"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Long Break" id="long-brk"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Short Break" id="short-brk"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 id=timer></h1>
        <div class="row">
            <ul id="buttons">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Start" id="start"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Stop" id="stop"></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="Reset" id="reset"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; Laere 2016</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be that your `querySelector('#` would be better as `getElementById(` and would vastly outperform the former

Comment: Yeah I actually have incorporated using querySelector over getElement in my projects a cpl weeks back. Thanks for the tip though too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `set...` functions are started with the buttons, you always initialise the times to starting values. Instead, if there is a timer already running you have to parse the paused time string into minutes and seconds and use those values to set your vars `mins` and `secs`.
Maybe something like this will work?

```
   function setPomodoro() {
        if(timer.innerHTML.length > 0){
            var t = timer.innerHTML.split(':');
            var mins = parseInt(t[0]);
            var secs = parseInt(t[1]);
        }
        else{
            var mins = 24;
            var secs = 60;
        }
        var intervalID = setInterval(function() { //set unique interval ID for each SI func.
                timer.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs;
                secs--;
                if (secs === 0) {
                    mins--;
                    secs = 60;
                } 
            }, 1000);
//      2.2 When stop button is clicked, timer stops
        stopButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
               clearInterval(intervalID);
        }, false);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Mind explaining the code a bit?

Comment: @Laere Sure, it's not complicated. It just checks if the timer string (like 11:55) has a non-zero length. If so it  doesn't use the default 24 and 60 but splits the displayed time at the colon resulting in an array `t`. the first element of that (`[0]`) is the minute, the 2nd element the seconds part. So when the timer starts again by setting the interval anew, it starts from the "saved" time.

Comment: makes sense, appreciate the explanation!